# How to find whether point is maxima/minima/saddle point for this case?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I read that we have a formula to check signs of

$f_{xx}*f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$      and       $f_{xx}$

And then we conclude whether the point is a maxima minima or saddle point for the given two variable function $f_{(x,y)}$

The text also states that for

$f_{xx}*f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$ $=0$  The test is inconclusive. So, how do we proceed for such points in the following example :

$f_{(x,y)}=2(x-y)^2-x^4-y^4$   at $(0,0)$ check maxima/minima/saddle point

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the second derivative test fails (i.e. the determinant of the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) is zero at that point)

We need to check by definition, we take a neighborhood of the point $(0,0)$ using some variables $h,k$, if the point $f(0+h, 0+k) - f(0,0) $ has a certain sign we know it is an extremum, if it is positive for all $h,k$ then we know it's maxima, negative minima, and if the sign is not known and depends on the variables then it's a saddle point.

$$ f(0+h, 0+k) -f(0,0) = f(h,k) -0 = 2(h-k)^2 -h^4 - k^4 $$

We can clearly choose some values for $h,k$ that would return a positive value, and some that return negative values, thus it is a saddle point.

Comment: Yeah, I did figure out that part but what I'm trying to find is a **general method**. Like the second derivative test is a general method. **In this case we are just putting values** for example we can show in this case for y=x and y=-x **but can't we do this with some general method??**

Comment: I cannot recall a general method if the second derivative test does not work @user14812745